# Flutter change body content

Tags: flutter, listener, setstate

[image]

Hello I made two buttons in home page Shops and Restaurants,When I press to Restaurants I want to change only  body content without changing appbar and bottom navigation bar,  so I need to change the state only, but I don't have an idea how to do it. Please provide and example code if it is possible.

P.S I did with Navigator.of(context).push but it is navigating to the new page and it is not what i want.
Here is the code i am using:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  main.selectedApp = 0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/HomeWidget");
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                        blurRadius: 1,
                        offset: Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: selected == 0
                        ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                        : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Shops",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: selected == 0
                              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                              : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  main.selectedApp = 1;
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/HomeWidget2");
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                        blurRadius: 1,
                        offset: Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: selected == 1
                        ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                        : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Restaurants",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: selected == 1
                              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                              : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` statement and `setstate`:

```
class SampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleWidgetState createState() => _SampleWidgetState();
}

class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SampleWidget> {
  int _activeWidget = 1;
  Widget _body(){
    switch (_activeWidget) {
      case 1:
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                _activeWidget = 2;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("I'm one"),
            )
        );
      case 2 :
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                _activeWidget = 0;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text("I'm two"),
            )
        );
      default:
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              _activeWidget = 1;
            });
          },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text("I'm zero"),
            )
        );
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _body(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I change the state of buttons then ? Like an active and inactive button under appbar ?

Comment: @Rock if you have just two buttons you can use a ternary operator like this `_activeWidget ==0 ? DO_SOMTHING : ELSE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Tab Bar** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html and Style it using this https://mightytechno.com/style-tabs-in-flutter-app/

Comment: I dont want to use tabbar, is theere any other way to make it ?